# How to insert string characters and numeric values together in the same matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, shuffle

I want to insert string characters(first column of my excel file) and numeric values(2nd to 11th column) in the same matrix in matlab, in order to perform random shuffling of the data. My data are in matrix of 314258 rows and 11 columns.

Many thanks for your helps.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a more complex data structure in Matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217041/creating-a-more-complex-data-structure-in-matlab) and [Combining a matrix of numbers, with array of strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16174833/combining-a-matrix-of-numbers-with-array-of-strings). For random shuffling you can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html)...

Comment: These are two separate questions, please look at `cell` matrices in matlab and try this yourself first. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/what-is-a-cell-array.html